# Understanding different values for nginx 'listen' directive

Tags: nginx

I'm writing nginx config, and I have a fundamental question.

What are the differences among:

`listen 443 ssl;` vs `listen [::]:443 ssl;` vs `listen [::]:443 ssl http2;`

My goal is secure this web application, but also remain compatible for old clients.

*Note: I understand that `[::]:443` has to with ipv6, but does it encompass ipv4 as well in this case? Want to clear my concepts.*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`listen 443 ssl` : makes nginx listen on all ipv4 address on the server, on port 443 (`0.0.0.0:443`)

while

`listen [::]:443 ssl` : makes nginx listen on all ipv6 address on the server, on port 443 (`:::443`)

---

`[::]:443` will not make nginx respond on ipv4 by default, unless you specify parameter `ipv6only=off` :

`listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off;`

---

As per the doc : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

ssl :

> The ssl parameter (0.7.14) allows specifying that all connections
> accepted on this port should work in SSL mode.

http2 :

> The http2 parameter (1.9.5) configures the port to accept [HTTP/2](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html) connections.

This doesn't mean it accepts only HTTP/2 connections.

As per [RFC7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.1)

> A client that makes a request for an "http" URI without prior
> knowledge about support for HTTP/2 on the next hop uses the HTTP
> Upgrade mechanism. The client does so by making an HTTP/1.1 request
> that includes an Upgrade header field with the "h2c" token.
>
> A server
> that does not support HTTP/2 can respond to the request as though the
> Upgrade header field were absent.

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 243 Content-Type: text/html`

> A server that supports HTTP/2
> accepts the upgrade with a 101 (Switching Protocols) response.  After
> the empty line that terminates the 101 response, the server can begin
> sending HTTP/2 frames.

To summarize :

A client that does not support HTTP/2 will never ask the server for an
HTTP/2 communication upgrade : the communication between them will be fully
HTTP1/1.

A client that supports HTTP/2 will ask the server (using HTTP1/1) for an HTTP/2 upgrade :

- If the server is HTTP/2 ready, then the server will notice the client
  as such : the communication between them will be switched to HTTP/2.
- If the server is not HTTP/2 ready, then the server will ignore the
  upgrade request answering with HTTP1/1 : the communication between
  them should stay plenty HTTP1/1.

Maybe more summarized here : http://qnimate.com/http2-compatibility-with-old-browsers-and-servers/

---

However the nginx doc states the following about HTTP/2 over TLS :

> Note that accepting HTTP/2 connections over TLS requires the
> “Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation” (ALPN) TLS extension support,
> which is available only since OpenSSL version 1.0.2.

Make sure old clients are compliant with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called `ipv6only` which determines whether or not the IPv6 address applies to IPv4 as well. By default it is turned on (which means it doesn't).

The manual states that it can only be set once, which I think means that if you turn it off in one `listen` directive, it is turned off for all.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for details.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) on HTTP/2.